# How to create a temp table in redshift to load csv data with varying number of columns in csv?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, dataframe, csv, amazon-redshift

I am trying to push data frame with varying number of columns to aws redshift.

this is the data frame header :

```
col1    col2    col3
```

I have created a temp table using something like this :

```
DROP TBALE TEMP;
CREATE TABLE temp (
    col1 int,
    col2 int,
    col3 int
);
```

but now the data frame has two new columns and the number of columns keeping changing.

How to drop create this table temp based on changing data frame columns

```
col1    col2    col3   col4    col5
```

any way to tackle this in one shot or do i keep editing ddl every time data is read

Comment: Who produces the csv files? Why are they different? Are you sure you should load them into the same table? etc.

Comment: Data pulled from Api. A python code creates a the csv. Yes it needs to be loaded in the same table. Is there no way to handle this instead of creating new table everytime the number of columns keep changing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are loading the data via a COPY command from S3, maybe you can try creating a table with the maximum number of columns you expect to receive in the CSV files, and then use the flag FILLRECORD (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-conversion.html#copy-fillrecord)

In this way if the file contains less columns, the other columns will have NULL values.
Example, if your file has 3 columns, but the TEMP table has 5:

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 5 | 6 | NULL | NULL |